# How to add to JSON value on external file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm wanting to see if it's possible to update a value on an external JSON file with python.

My JSON file, called `inventory.json`.

```
{
    "sword": 1,
    "shield": 0,
    "key": 0
}
```

Is it possible to use a command, such as for example:

```
data["shield"] += 1
data["shield"] += 7
```

to update the JSON file's value for sword by one so the file looks like this?

```
{
    "sword": 2,
    "shield": 7,
    "key": 0
}
```

Comment: Read the JSON into a dict, increment the values, write it back to the file.

Comment: Yes.  Read the JSON file into a dict, update the dict and dump back into a file.  I’ll let you work out the details.  Tip: there is a library called `json`.

Comment: Read the json, update the value, write back to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other commentors are completely correct.  A good solution to this problem is to import the json library, using `import json` at the top of your code. Then, you can use:

```
json_file = open("file.json", "r")
json_text = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
json_dict = json.loads(json_text)
```

After this, you will have the JSON dictionary object "json_dict".  You can modify the values in this dictionary by key, for example `json_dict['sword']+=3` or `json_dict['name'] = "Marc"`.  When you are finished with all of the modification you would like to make, you can write the JSON dict to the file.

```
writing_file = open("file.json","w")
writing_file.write(json.dumps(json_dict))
writing_file.close()
```

If you'd like, you can do this as a function to update the JSON file by putting the last three lines in a function that just takes a dict.  json.loads() takes a json formatted string and converts it into a Python dictionary, json.dumps() takes a Python dictionary and converts it into a json formatted string.

In general, it is better to keep values in memory by using them as a variable (json_dict) than it is to constantly read and write a file, simply because you can't just jump to the 'sword' index in a file, you have to search for it.